# VuePress not rendering `<router-link>` tags

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuepress

I am using VuePress (`^1.0.3`) for a side project, with a fairly straightforward setup. I'm not sure when this started occurring, currently the `<router-link>` elements don't get rendered as `<a>` tags, but show up as `<div>` (without linking functionality/interactivity). You can see what's going wrong here, for instance in the bottom menu bar items (or the space 'tiles' that should be clickable): https://new.coworkberlin.com/

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vuepress dev .",
    "build": "vuepress build ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vuepress/plugin-google-analytics": "^1.0.3",
    "@vuepress/plugin-pwa": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.6",
    "vuepress": "^1.0.3",
    "vuepress-plugin-sitemap": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

The repository for this project is github.com/ldanielswakman/cowork-berlin

Does anybody have any idea of how I might fix this?

Comment: It seems like you are using a customize layout, right? Can you provide more detail for the relevant code? Maybe a repo or code snippets.

Comment: Ah yes, good point! The repo is available here: https://github.com/ldanielswakman/cowork-berlin

And yes indeed, I'm using a custom theme with VuePress; so for instance a place where `<router-link>` elements are used but not rendered correctly is https://github.com/ldanielswakman/cowork-berlin/blob/master/.vuepress/theme/components/AppNav.vue

Comment: Well, the link you provided is invalid, so I'm guessing it's a private repo. Anyway, my suggestions would be updating Vuepress to the latest version and use Yarn instead of npm. Put the relevant code snippets here would be more helpful.

Comment: Ah yes you’re right I’m sorry about that. I just made the repository public (temporarily). I am using the latest version of vuepress and I am using yarn... can you see anything from the setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extract the relevant code, in case I can't solve your problem and you need to make your repo private again.

I couldn't run your repo successfully and got lots of errors, so I'm not sure if this will work.

The origin code:

```html
<router-link :to="'/'">
    <i v-if="!isHomePage"></i>
    <h1>
        <img :src="$withBase('/logo.svg')"/>
    </h1>
</router-link>
```

You can try to change it into:

```html
<router-link to="/">
    <i v-if="!isHomePage"></i>
    <h1>
        <img src="$withBase('/logo.svg')"/>
    </h1>
</router-link>
```

1. `""` or `''` would be enough, you do not need both of them.
2. You do not need `:` either since `/` is not a variable, and apparently won't change.

BTW, I also suggest you:

1. Update `Vuepress` to the latest version, which is `1.2.0`
2. Take a look at your dependencies, cause I get errors while running `yarn install`

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting here! I had been running `yarn upgrade` to update my dependencies, but I didn't realise this only did minor version updates (I'm not too familiar with yarn/npm). So I made sure VuePress was updated to 1.2.0, and that solved the problem! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to not only do minor version updates via `yarn upgrade` but also 'manually' update VuePress to the latest version (`1.2.0`) — that solved the issue.